# If / Else if statement reduction

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

From my server, I get a XML list with "Timelines" that are running.
When a Timeline is in a "Running"or "Held at end" state a button will be in an active state.

I have done it this way and it works.
But I would like to turn down the "Else" statements in my code.
Any ideas?

```
 function statusCheck()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/query/timelineStatus?id=1-30",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find("timelineStatus").each(function(){
                var timelineId = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
                var playState = $(this).find("playState").text();
                if (timelineId == 1) // timeline_1
                {
                    changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_1", (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
                }
                else if (timelineId == 2) // timeline_2
                {
                    changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_2", (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
                }
                else if (timelineId == 3) // timeline_3
                {
                    changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_3", (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
                }
                else if (timelineId == 4) // timeline_4
                {
                    changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_4", (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
                }
                else if (timelineId == 5) // timeline_5
                {
                    changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_5", (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
                }
                else if (timelineId == 6) // timeline_6
                {
                    changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_6", (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
                }

        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how standard your id naming is, you could just use a small string concatenation.

```
function statusCheck()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/query/timelineStatus?id=1-30",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find("timelineStatus").each(function(){
                var timelineId = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
                var playState = $(this).find("playState").text();
                if (timelineId > 0 && timelineId <= 6) {
                    changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_" + timelineId, (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Using the trick above works but in the Chrome Dashboard it shows a problem with splitting the string:

function changeJQMThemeSwatch(selector, swatch)
{
" var classList = $(selector).attr("class").split(/\s+/);"

I know it has something to do with /\s+/ but I can't figure out what a correct notation would be.

Answer (score 1):

what about doing it dynamically?

```
changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_"+timelineId, (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
```

Answer (score 0):

If all of your `#timeline_x` values follow this pattern, just do this:

```
function statusCheck()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/query/timelineStatus?id=1-30",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find("timelineStatus").each(function(){
                var timelineId = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
                var playState = $(this).find("playState").text();
                if(timelineId > 0 && timelineId <= 6) { // change as needed
                     changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_" + timelineId, (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
                }
            }
        })
    });
}
```

If you need to use different logic for some values, use `switch` instead:

```
function statusCheck()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/query/timelineStatus?id=1-30",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find("timelineStatus").each(function(){
                var timelineId = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
                var playState = $(this).find("playState").text();
                switch(timelineId) {
                    case 1:
                        changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_1", (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_2", (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_3", (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
                    break;
                    case 4:
                        changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_4", (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
                    break;
                    case 5:
                        changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_5", (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
                    break;
                    case 6:
                        changeJQMThemeSwatch("#timeline_6", (playState == "Running" || playState == "Held at end") ? "b" : "a");
                    break;
                }
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: I have used the first one with the extra "IF" line and it works fine.
Without the "IF" line it did not worked.
I'm still in a learning curve and a group like this is great help in this matter.

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to select an answer! :)